# kendo ui grid date sorting is not working

Tags: kendo-ui

I am trying to sort my data on desc date order but I can't, I keep getting an asc ordering on my kendo ui grid, here is the code.

```
this.gridConfig = {
        dataSource: {
            transport: {
                read: '/api/endpoint,
                dataType: 'json'
            },
            schema: {
                data: "my_data_var"
            }
        },
        sort: { field: "date", dir: "desc"},
        resizable: true,
        filterable: true,
        pageable: {
            pageSize: 200
        },
        columns: [{
            field: 'date',
            title: 'Date',
            template: "#= kendo.toString(kendo.parseDate(date, 'yyyy-MM-dd'), 'dd/MMM/yyyy') #"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sort option is a dataSource configuration so it should be :

```
   dataSource: {
        transport: {
            read: '/api/endpoint,
            dataType: 'json'
        },
        schema: {
            data: "my_data_var"
        },
        sort: { field: "date", dir: "desc"}
    },
```